# Google Maps V3 - Switching on/off groups of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently trying to use Google Maps with a bunch of markers on it (extracted from a JSON data file). I want to be able to group the markers in one of two categories and be able to switch them off or on.

I am up to the point where the map is working, the pointers are showing and the switch buttons are flicking on and off - all that is left now is to add the markers to groups and bind the switch buttons to displaying/hiding the markers on the map.

I know that I can use `marker.setVisible(false/true)` but I'm not sure how or where to use it.

I am new to using Google Maps API v3 so any direction with this would be much appreciated.

I have setup a fiddle with what I have so far, you can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/6n25g3n7/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `markers` variable been access to your click event.

Code example:

```
var markers = [];

function addMarkerToMap(map, markerData){
    for(var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++){    
      // init marker

      markers.push(marker);  //push to marker's array
    }
}

function clickEvent(){
    for(var key in markers){
        markers[key].setVisible(true/false);

    }
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n25g3n7/5/ Sorry about code is a little bit mess.

If you have any question about code, please comment :)

Comment: Hi Weigreen, thanks for your response - I checked out the fiddle but it's exactly the same as my one, there's no change :(

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! now, is there a way to group the markers and bind them to their switches?

Comment: As far as i know, there may not be a way to do so :( Maybe you can use different array or dimension to group your markers.

Comment: see this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove google's doc have a `clearMarkers()` it use for loop for all markers

Comment: @thePav Check my answer

Comment: @weigreen, thanks I'm going to check this out and I'll be back with a result in a few minutes

Comment: @weigreen, I got it to work with two groups :) Thanks for your help! You can check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/6n25g3n7/9/ I basically added two separate arrays for the markers and targeted them based on the group type

Answer (score 0):

This one has both markers turning on and off. Check the jsfiddle for all the changes. I had to re-structure some of your code.

```
function createSwitches(markers){
    var html = '<div class="switches"><span class="switch-title">Show Me</span></div>';

    // ADD YOU SWITCHES HERE! 
    // Make sure the same order as the google markers
    var all_switches = [
        { 
            html: '<span class="whats-on-wrapper"><span data-target="whats-on" class="switch switch-on">Item Group 2</span></span>',
        },
        {
            html: '<span class="stand-wrapper"><span data-target="stand" class="switch switch-on">Item Group 1</span></span>',
        }
    ];

    // Add the main bar element  
    $('.map-container').prepend(html);

    // Loop through all your switches and add them 
    // with the event
    for (var i = 0; i < all_switches.length; i++) {

        var element = $(all_switches[i]["html"]);

        (function(index, element, markers) {
            $(element).on('click',  function () {
            var this_marker = markers[index];
            var current = String(this_marker.visible);
            var toggle  = ( current === "true") ? false : true;

            this_marker.setVisible(toggle);

            });
        })(i, element, markers)


        $('.switches').append($(element))
    }

    // Set the toggle animation
    $('.switches .switch').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('switch-on');
        $(this).toggleClass('switch-off');
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6n25g3n7/8/

Comment: Hi e4en, thanks for your response. I will have more map pointers eventually so I can't just target them by array keys.

Comment: @thePav Done. Just make sure you add the google markers in the same order. Then add your html to the array and you're good. Accept the answer if this is everything.

Comment: I will have 2 groups possibly containing up to 20 markers each which will be fed through to the script from a CMS post type (Wordpress). I only need to turn the groups on and off, not the individual markers. There's no way of knowing the exact order.

Comment: Instead of passing just the raw marker elements to this then, when you create them at the top, put them into and object with their group id and return that. That way you don't need the array.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I attach a group to the markers?

Comment: Im busy atm, but create a jsfiddle with 4 markers from my code and get that working and ill change it when i can.

Comment: Thanks for your help e4en, however there is a way that we can do it via arrays, see the answer from @weigreen and see my last comment.